# Best way to capture the flow

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am dealing with 30 micro rest services each having different flow.  I am also dealing with some EJB related service.  I am also dealing with scheduled job related flows as well. There are hundreds of stored procedures involved from database side. How to capture each flow so that i refreshes my memory when i visit same flow say after few days, weeks also flow keep evolving daily with changes? My mind works well with pictures than words. Any best practices you follow  around this. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably opinion-based, and questions for tools and libraries are off-topic. I'd do a web search for tools that can map my infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a flow with many components the best and most suitable way to keep trace of it is with [sequence diagrams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram). They are ment just for that, to keep the ordered communication path between the different participant of a flow.

There are plenty of tools out there to build sequence diagrams, some of them are even online and you don't need to do graphic stuff, you just code them and the tool prints it for you.

Comment: Tools like https://sequencediagram.org/ or https://www.websequencediagrams.com